# problems with pygame controller support

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
import os
import random
import time
import json
from pygame import joystick
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1920, 1000
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

#load images
RED_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "pixel_ship_red_small.png")), (125, 100))
GREEN_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "pixel_ship_green_small.png")), (125, 100))
BLUE_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "pixel_ship_blue_small.png")), (125, 100))
#player
YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "spaceship_yellow.png")), (154, 121)), 180)
#lasers
RED_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "pixel_laser_red.png"))
BLUE_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "pixel_laser_blue.png"))
GREEN_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "pixel_laser_green.png"))
#player laser
YELLOW_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "pixel_laser_yellow.png"))
#background
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'space.png')), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

class Laser():
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = img
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
    
    def move(self, vel):
        self.y += vel

    def off_screen(self, height):
        return not(self.y <= height and self.y >= 0)

    def collision(self, obj):
        return collide(self, obj)

class Ship:
    COOLDOWN = 30

    def __init__(self, x, y, health = 100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.ship_img = None
        self.laser_img = None
        self.lasers = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y))
        for laser in self.lasers:
            laser.draw(window)

    def move_lasers(self, vel, obj):
        self.cooldown()
        for laser in self.lasers:
            laser.move(vel)
            if laser.off_screen(HEIGHT):
                self.lasers.remove(laser)
            elif laser.collision(obj):
                obj.health -= 10
                self.lasers.remove(laser)
    
    def cooldown(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter >= self.COOLDOWN:
            self.cool_down_counter = 0
        elif self.cool_down_counter > 0:
            self.cool_down_counter += 1

    def shoot(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter == 0:
            laser = Laser(self.x, self.y, self.laser_img)
            self.lasers.append(laser)
            self.cool_down_counter = 1

    def get_width(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_width()

    def get_height(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_height()

class Player(Ship):
    def __init__(self, x, y, health = 100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.ship_img = YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP
        self.laser_img = YELLOW_LASER
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
        self.max_health = health
    
    def shoot(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter == 0:
            laser = Laser(self.x + 26, self.y - 57, self.laser_img)
            self.lasers.append(laser)
            self.cool_down_counter = 1
    
    def move_lasers(self, vel, objs):
        self.cooldown()
        for laser in self.lasers:
            laser.move(vel)
            if laser.off_screen(HEIGHT):
                self.lasers.remove(laser)
            else:
                for obj in objs:
                    if laser.collision(obj):
                        objs.remove(obj)
                        if laser in self.lasers:
                            self.lasers.remove(laser)

    def draw(self, window):
        super().draw(window)
        self.healthbar(window)

    def healthbar(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y + self.ship_img.get_height() + 10, self.ship_img.get_width(), 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y + self.ship_img.get_height() + 10, self.ship_img.get_width()* (self.health/self.max_health),10))

class Enemy(Ship):
    COLOR_MAP = {
                "red": (RED_SPACE_SHIP, RED_LASER),
                "green": (GREEN_SPACE_SHIP, GREEN_LASER),
                "blue": (BLUE_SPACE_SHIP, BLUE_LASER)
                }
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, health = 100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.ship_img, self.laser_img = self.COLOR_MAP[color]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)

    def move(self, vel):
        self.y += vel

    def shoot(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter == 0:
            laser = Laser(self.x - 3, self.y + 20, self.laser_img)
            self.lasers.append(laser)
            self.cool_down_counter = 1

def collide(obj1, obj2):
    offset_x = obj2.x - obj1.x
    offset_y = obj2.y - obj1.y
    return obj1.mask.overlap(obj2.mask, (offset_x, offset_y)) != None 



def main():
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    level = 0
    lives = 5
    lost = False
    lost_count = 0
    main_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 75)
    lost_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 500)

    enemies = []
    wave_length = 5

    player_vel = 7
    laser_vel = 7
    enemy_vel = 1

    player = Player(WIDTH // 2, 650)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def redraw_window():
        WIN.blit(BG, (0,0))
        #draw text
        level_label = main_font.render(f"Level: {level}", 1, WHITE)
        lives_label = main_font.render(f"Lives: {lives}", 1, WHITE)

        WIN.blit(lives_label, (10, 10))
        WIN.blit(level_label, (WIDTH - level_label.get_width() - 10, 10))

        player.draw(WIN)

        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.draw(WIN)

        if lost:
            lost_label = lost_font.render("You Lost!", 1, (WHITE))
            WIN.blit(lost_label, (WIDTH/2 - lost_label.get_width()/2, HEIGHT / 2 - lost_label.get_height() / 2))

        pygame.display.update()
    joysticks = []
    for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count()):
        joysticks.append(pygame.joystick.Joystick(i))
    for joystick in joysticks:
        pygame.joystick.init()
        print(pygame.joystick.get_init())

    with open(os.path.join("ps4_keys.json"), 'r+') as file:
        button_keys = json.load(file)

    # 0: Left analog horizonal, 1: left analog verticle, 2: right analog horizonal
    # 3: right analog verticle, 4: left Triger, 5: Right Trigger
    analog_keys = {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:-1, 5:-1} 

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        redraw_window()

        if lives <= 0 or player.health <= 0:
            lost = True
            lost_count += 1
        
        if lost:
            if lost_count > FPS * 3:
               run = False 
            else:
                continue

        if len(enemies) == 0:
            level += 1
            wave_length += 5
            for i in range(wave_length):
                enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(100, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"]))
                enemies.append(enemy)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
                analog_keys[event.axis] = event.value
                print(analog_keys)
                if abs(analog_keys[0]) > .4:
                    if analog_keys[0] < -.7:
                        player.x -= 7
                    else:
                        continue
                    if analog_keys[0] < .7:
                        player.x += 7

        for enemy in enemies[:]:
            enemy.move(enemy_vel)
            enemy.move_lasers(laser_vel, player)

            if random.randrange(0, 120) == 1:
                enemy.shoot()

            if collide(enemy, player):
                player.health -= 10
                enemies.remove(enemy)

            elif enemy.y + enemy.get_height() > HEIGHT:
                lives -= 1
                enemies.remove(enemy)

        player.move_lasers(-laser_vel, enemies)

def main_menu():
    title_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 150)
    run = True
    while run:
        WIN.blit(BG, (0,0))
        title_label = title_font.render("Click the mouse to begin...", 1, WHITE)
        WIN.blit(title_label, (WIDTH / 2 - title_label.get_width() / 2, HEIGHT / 2 - title_label.get_height() / 2))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                main()

    pygame.quit()

main_menu()
```

^^^
so this is my code (here is the JSON file as well):

```
{
    "x": 0,
    "circle": 1,
    "square": 2,
    "triangle": 3,
    "share": 4,
    "PS": 5,
    "options": 6,
    "left_stick_click": 7,
    "right_stick_click": 8,
    "L1": 9,
    "R1": 10,
    "up_arrow": 11,
    "down_arrow": 12,
    "left_arrow": 13,
    "right_arrow": 14,
    "touchpad": 15
    
}
```

I'm trying to make the player be controlled by the controller left joystick and it returns no errors but my player does not move and it is printing true from the `print(pygame.joystick.get_init())` and printing the joystick amounts from: `print(analog_keys)` but the player does not move. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `JOYAXISMOTION` event. The event does not occur continuously, it only occurs once when the axis changes.
Use [`pygame.joystick.Joystick.get_axis`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html#pygame.joystick.Joystick) to get the current position of the axis and move the player depending on the axis:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while run:
        # [...]
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        if joysticks:
            joystick = joysticks[0]
            axis_x, axis_y = (joystick.get_axis(0), joystick.get_axis(1))
            if abs(axis_x) > 0.1:
                player.x += round(7 * axis_x)
            if abs(axis_y) > 0.1:
                player.y += round(7 * axis_y)

        # [...]
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x, y = window.get_rect().center

if pygame.joystick.get_count() > 0:
    joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    joystick.init()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    axis_x, axis_y = (joystick.get_axis(0), joystick.get_axis(1))
    if abs(axis_x) > 0.1:
        x = (x + round(7 * axis_x)) % window.get_width()
    if abs(axis_y) > 0.1:
        y = (y + round(7 * axis_y)) % window.get_height()   

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), (x, y), 10)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: oh ok I will try this as soon as I get a chance and come back with the results

Comment: I got a new error: https://hatebin.com/giikqtjqhr (couldn't fit it in the character restriction) this error occurs when I move the joystick

Comment: @Nightslash19 `player.x += round(7 * axis_x)` and `player.y += round(7 * axis_y)`. I've changed the code in the answer.

Comment: ok this works thank you I was going to say it didn't but I had some wrong indentations